# Sweep with two shift registers

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c, code-optimization

I am working with 8 dual color LED's and 2 shift registers. My connections are in place. But I do not understand how to work with 2 shift registers.

So I am trying to make this: turn the first led on, turn the first led of, go to the next led, turn it on, turn in off, etc...

I do not know how to jump from the first shift register to the second shift register when the last LED of the first shift register is turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same as when you're trying to keep them dark when lighting an LED with the first register: shift two bytes.

The first byte shifts into the first register to begin with, and then *out* of the first register and *into* the second register when you shift the second byte into the first register. Just make sure only the appropriate bits are set in both bytes and you're good to go.